# Stoping items on webpage moving when resize the browser

Tags: html, css, browser, resize, window

Im trying to figure out what needs to be done to the css of the holy grail layout to stop the items from moving when the browser is re sized.

http://puu.sh/aduy9/63014e4039.css

Thats my css file i cant get it to all copy and paste into this box so i uploaded it with puush

Any help is much wanted and apreciated.

Comment: It would be much easier if you could make a jsfiddler for us to view.  The CSS alone doesn't do much for us.

Answer (score 0):

try to change position of the layout style to *absolute* or *fixed* or another one is *relative*.
example:

```
.some_layout{
   position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am guessing right, you are talking about the elements moving around when you resize the browser causing width change of the page.

Try to set min-width for your content wrapper and also set overflow-x to hidden. 
For Example:

```
div#content {
  min-width: 800px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Hope this help